# Cross platform reverse proxy with lighttpd

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd

I have a website `www.somewebsite.com` domain hosted on lighttpd **1.4** server configured with `server.port = 8080` that is on a device **(A)** with local IP `192.168.1.26` and I want to get to use a reverse proxy in order to access another server that runs on a different device **(B)** at `192.168.1.30:80/myapp`in order to be accessed as

```
somewebsite.com/myapp
```

In device **(A)** server config I have enabled `mod_proxy`
and I have tried to add

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^.*myapp" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => 
        (( "(www.)?somewebsite.com" => "192.168.1.30", "port" => 80 ))
    )
}
```

but I get internal server error page when I try to access `somewebsite.com/myapp`

I have tried also

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/myapp/)" {   
  proxy.server  = ( "" => ("" => ( "(www.)?somewebsite.com" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8080 ))) 
}

$SERVER["socket"] == ":81" {   
  url.rewrite-once = ( "^/myapp/(.*)$" => "/$1" )   
  proxy.server  = ( "" => ( "" => ( "(www.)?somewebsite.com" => "192.168.1.30", "port" => 80 ))) 
}
```

but the result is even worse and server crashes completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proxy.server` do not take host as an argument, and "host" is a keyword, not a place to put your host here.

Try this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(www.)?somewebsite.com" {
 $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/myapp/" {
  url.rewrite-once = ("^/myapp/(.*)" => "/newapp/$1") # If you need to rewrite context.
  proxy.server  =  ( "" => ( "" => ("host" => "192.168.1.30", "port" => 80 )))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have flushed DNS cache and it works. However if I want to alias the `/myapp` subpath linked with reverse proxy using another name e.g. `somewebsite.com/othername` how should I do?

Comment: Look at my edited answer.

Comment: @kaboom I have tried but unfortunately this doesn't work. I get not found error if I try to access `somewebsite.com/newapp`

Comment: You have to look into both lighttpd and backend logs - what url is coming and what error is produced. And also check browser internals via "inspect" mode. It may be a specific of how backend works.

Comment: seems that `url.rewrite` doesn't work in `HTTP["url"]` block

Comment: It was a bug before 1.4.34, you may still hit it. Anyway it should be out of "url" block not to confuse original context and proxy context.

Answer (score 2):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(www.)?somewebsite.com" {
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/myapp/" {
    url.rewrite-once = ("^/myapp/(.*)" => "/newapp/$1")
  }
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/newapp/" {
    proxy.server  =  ( "" => ( "" => ("host" => "192.168.1.30", "port" => 80 )))
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `proxy.header` with `"map-urlpath"` with lighttpd 1.4.46 and later.  See https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy